# Count IDs from current month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to count the number of ID's for the current month in a table called bike_main with a column for ID and a column for date. The current command returns 541853 which is the total number of IDs

```
    $monthlyRiders= 'SELECT id FROM bike_main WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
    $monthlyRidersResult=mysql_query($monthlyRiders);
    $monthlyRidersRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($monthlyRidersResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not counting the ids here, you are fetching all ids within the month.
And with `mysql_fetch_assoc` you will get the last one (which can also represent the total number of ids).

To count the number of rows, use this :

```
$monthlyRiders= 'SELECT count(id) as number_of_rows FROM bike_main WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
$monthlyRidersResult=mysql_query($monthlyRiders);
$monthlyRidersRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($monthlyRidersResult);
```

Or alternatively select your rows, then use `mysqli_num_rows()` (this is slower).